# Why am I not able to remove all containers in docker

Tags: docker, containers, docker-engine

I have existing containers :

```
e158b26e4147

4dd41f8431f2

06cbbb00dcf1

14d1ceb499b2
```

I want to delete all of them. So I used the command `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`.
But I am getting following error:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker rm --help'.
```

What can be the solution?

Comment: Check if the answer helps you, and also check your commands and character again. What OS are you in?

Comment: Run `docker -v` to see your version

Comment: @Saeed I am using windows with docker version 20.10.8

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but it seems you should run it on PowerShell. Be sure you're not on CMD

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

**docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)**

Comment: I am getting error :   unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker rm --help'.

Comment: Did you try removing the -a option from command. Like this : docker rm -f $(docker ps -q)

Comment: Also please note that if OS is Windows , pls try from powershell instead of cmd. This is a known issue on Windows.

Comment: I am getting error - docker rm -f $(docker ps -q)